# cURL returning bool(false) when making a SOAP request

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP request using cURL but I am getting the following errors. For the output of the result, I get "**bool(false)**". For the curl_error() function, I get "**Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received**".

My question is whether I am missing something that could be preventing the connection, possibly in the cURL options?

This is my code:

```
<?php
function soap_subscriber($subscriber_email) {

    $soap_endpoint = '[HIDDEN]';
    $soap_username = '[HIDDEN]';
    $soap_userpass = '[HIDDEN]';

    define('USERNAME', '[HIDDEN]');
    define('PASSWORD', '[HIDDEN]');
    define('ENDPOINT', $soap_endpoint);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Nassau');

    $ch = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
                        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        <soap:Header>
                            <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
                                <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-884da619-59bb-4db6-834d-138322342442">
                                    <wsse:Username> . soap_username . </wsse:Username>
                                    <wsse:Password
                                        Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"
                                        > . soap_userpass . </wsse:Password>
                                </wsse:UsernameToken>
                            </wsse:Security>
                        </soap:Header>
                        <soap:Body>
                            <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                                <RetrieveRequest>
                                    <ClientIDs>
                                        <ID>[HIDDEN]</ID>
                                    </ClientIDs>
                                    <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[HIDDEN]</ObjectType>
                                    <Properties>SubscriberID</Properties>
                                    <Properties>FirstName</Properties>
                                    <Properties>Email</Properties>
                                          <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
                                           <q1:Property>Email</q1:Property>
                                           <q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
                                           <q1:Value> . $subscriber_email . </q1:Value>
                                        </Filter>
                                </RetrieveRequest>
                            </RetrieveRequestMsg>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>';

        $soap_header = array(
            "Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: ",
            "Content-length: ".strlen($ch),
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        $curl_options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => ENDPOINT,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => USERNAME . ':' . PASSWORD,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $ch,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $soap_header,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

   var_dump($response);
   var_dump($error);

}

soap_subscriber('[HIDDEN]');

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using CURL for SOAP? PHP has a [SOAP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Okay, I will try this as part of a function in Drupal instead of cURL.

Comment: Sounds good, good luck!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Can I confirm that I would not need to install anything if I am using this in a custom module for Drupal 7?

Comment: I do not know, it depends on your PHP installation. You need to make sure the SOAP extension is enabled. You can verify this by either checking the `php.ini` file or look through the output of `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP request requires more than 30 seconds to finish its execution. Some solutions you can try:

- Increase cURL operation time limit:

  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); // 400 seconds`
- Set `set_time_limit` to 0 to make your requests run for infinite seconds:

  `set_time_limit(0);`

  but downside is that hanging or running out of memory is possible.
- Try adding this to your cURL options to prevent infinite redirection from the server:

  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried making these changes. Now I get the following error: string(45) "OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54"

Comment: Do you know what could be causing the OpenSSL error?

Comment: `Error 54` means unable to connect. That's why you're getting a timeout. Could be an issue with the `SSL certificate` installation or configuration of the URL you're trying to connect to or because of outdated CA root certificate bundle.

Comment: Can me testing it locally cause this error? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try to test your `ENDPOINT` SSL online. Here's one you can use: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Read thru the errors and we can debug from there. If there's nothing wrong with the SSL, the problem is in your PHP and cURL configurations.

Comment: It was given a B rating. The only error I can see is the 
HTTP Requests which had a 403 status code. Is there anything else that I need to look out for?